# Using demand and offer to Clusterize

Tags: machine-learning, python, optimization

I have the following scenario:

[image: Lat_Long Points].

Input is a  set of lat_long Points. Every Point has a **demand**, like 20 children that need to go to school.

I want to create a random set of schools (points) that will attend the demand for each Point. I.e: The school A is on Point(x,y) and has a capacity for 100 children. Therefore it will attend P1(demand=20), P2 (demand=30), P3(demand=70), creating this new cluster.

[image: k-mean or Dbscan]

A regular cluster method will cluster the dataset using distance. How would I classify the sample with the demand/offer ??

Comment: I'm not too familiar with econometrics, but that sounds more like an optimal transport rather than a clustering problem

Comment: The problem with **optimization** is that I need to define some initial points. What I am trying to solve is this initial points by classifying the demand points to schools until they are filled, and then going to another cluster. This **could** give me all the possible Schools, for the 3 different sizes, after that i would run a proper distance optimization